# JSON - Validating a Json array or Object

Tags: javascript, json

Here's 2 javascript variables:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var example1 = 'Mr.:1|Mrs.:2|Ms.:3|Dr.:4|Sr.:5|Jr.:6';
var example2 = {'Mr.':'1','Mrs.':'2','Ms.':'3','Dr.':'4','Sr.':'5','Jr.':'6'}
</script>
```

With javascript, is there a way to detect which one is not `json`?

Comment: Neither of those are JSON. Please explain what you're actually looking for

Comment: Actually neither one of the examples are JSON. The JSON spec requires that properties and string values be wrapped in double quotes (`"`), therefore neither example above is JSON. For the full spec, see [this](http://www.json.org/) page.

Comment: the first is a string, the second is an object,  you can check on that if you wish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the JSON.parse function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This will throw an exception if the text passed into it is not valid JSON.

Edit:

The comments noting that you have not pasted JSON code are correct. This code:

```
var json = {"var1":"val1"};
```

Is actually a JavaScript Object. It looks remarkably similar, and it's quite easy to go between the two (using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse) but they are different concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Use try catch and handle accordingly:

```
function IsJsonString(str) {
  try {
      JSON.parse(str);
  } catch (e) {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the type of the variable in js,

You can try this

```
typeof("somevalue")
//returns string
```

typeof array or object will return you 'object'
like

```
var arr = [];
typeof(arr) // returns 'object'
```

Comment: While `typeof` will tell you the type of the value in a javascript variable, it does not tell you whether a string value is valid JSON or not.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
try {
    JSON.parse(example1);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(example1+' is not valid JSON');
}
```